# jQuery Mask clipboard repeating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel and jQuery, and trying to validate a CPF/CNPJ field. CPF and CNPJ are Brazilian tax registration numbers for individuals (CPF) and companies (CNPJ).

The CPF should be formatted like this: `999.999.999-99`. The CNPJ should be formatted like this: `99.999.999/9999-99`. So if I put 14 character string, it should be considered a CPF, and if I put a 18 length string, it should be considered a CNPJ.

This is the form in .blade.php:

```
<div class="widget">
            <h4 class="widgettitle">Dados do Comprador</h4>
            <div class="widgetcontent" id="form-comprador">
                {{Form::hidden('comprador[tipopessoa]')}}
                {{Form::hidden('comprador[tipocontribuinte]', 'C')}}
                {{Form::hidden('comprador[id]', $comprador->getId())}}

                {{Form::label('CPF/CNPJ')}}
                {{Form::text('comprador[cpfcnpj]', null, array('class' => 'input-block-level cpfcnpj'))}}

                {{Form::label('Nome/Razão Social')}}
                {{Form::text('comprador[nomerazao]', null, array('class' => 'input-block-level'))}}

                {{Form::label('E-mail')}}
                {{Form::text('comprador[email]', null, array('class' => 'input-block-level'))}}

                {{Form::label('Telefone')}}
                {{Form::text('comprador[telefone]', null, array('class' => 'input-block-level telefone'))}}

            </div>
        </div>
```

The mask in .js code:

```
jQuery('.cpfcnpj').inputmask({
mask: ['999.999.999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99'],
clearIncomplete: true,
oncomplete: function(){
    if($(this).val().length <= 14){
        $("input[name='pessoa[tipopessoa]']").val('F');
        $('div #pessoafisica').show();
        $('div #pessoajuridica').hide();
    }else{
        $("input[name='pessoa[tipopessoa]']").val('J');
        $('div #pessoafisica').hide();
        $('div #pessoajuridica').show();
    }
},
onincomplete: function(){
        $('div #pessoafisica').hide();
        $('div #pessoajuridica').hide();
}
});
```

When I type directly, it works fine, but if I copy and paste a CPF, it appends the 3 first digits and is considered a CNPJ. For example:

`012.345.678.99` or `01234567899` is pasted as `01.234.567/8990-12`

I didn't find anything about clipboard repeating digits like that, and I have no clue why it's happening.